# Quando usar um Fragment no lugar de uma Activity

Tags: android, android-fragment

Estou trabalhando em um projeto onde estou fazendo o uso de vários `fragments` e apenas uma `activity`. Dando uma pesquisada, vi que muitos lugares sugerem o uso de `fragments` quando o código do mesmo será reutilizado e, por isso, me questionei onde deveria usar `fragments` e onde seria mais interessante usar `activities`.

O fluxo do meu projeto segue da seguinte maneira;

```
Tela de login > Tela de lista > tela de inserção de item na lista
                              > tela de visualização de item da lista
                              > tela de itens removidos da lista > tela de visualização de itens removidos da lista
                              > tela de relatórios
```

Não sei se ficou claro o fluxograma, no momento estou sem nenhum programa para fazer algo mais adequado. No meu caso, existe apenas uma `activity` em todas essas telas, e dessas apenas as telas de visualização são reutilizadas (mesmo `fragment`). Todas as outras são `fragments` que, apesar de serem utilizadas constantemente, não são **reutilizadas**.

Minha dúvida é: onde, nesse cenário, é melhor o uso de `activities` no lugar dos `fragments`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É considera boa pratica usar activity no caso de um fluxo unico, por exemplo, digamos que dentro da tela de edição do item voce colocasse a opção do usuario selecionar um icone pra aquele item, o fluxo que voce fizesse depois disso seria um caminho unico (o usuario poderia selecionar imagens que voce adicionou no aplicativo ou selecionar uma imagem da galeria). Essa tela de seleção só é acessivel a partir da tela de adição de item na lista, não sendo reaproveitada por nenhuma outra. Outro ponto importante é que voce não quer que durante a seleção de icone o usuario va para a tela da lista de itens já criados ou para a relatorios, voce quer que o usuario termine de selecionar o item ou cancele a operação(voce nao precisa ficar salvando o estado desta dela uma vez que ele concluiu o que esta fazendo).